# how to get the middle imagein css background?

Tags: css

[image]

I want to insert only red color image inside the div.

I want to do css sprite. the problem is I have 3 images like this. but the div will be 900px. How to get the middle image into the div?

```css
#a {
    background: url(../img/a.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: `background:#ED1C24`?

Comment: What in the world... what do you want? What `div`?

Comment: What is the issue? Can you provide more details?

Comment: i know color code. Its a demo. I want to put others image. It will be css sprite

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To use sprite technic, you need a separate element with dimensions equal to your image on a spritesheet. It's possible to use pseudo-element for this purpose:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.container::before {
    content: '';

    /* Vertical centering */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;

    /* Sprite */        
    display: block;
    width: 31px;
    height: 69px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpoSb.png) -30px 0;
}

/* Put all the children in front of ::before */
.container > * {
    position: relative;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tPLXF/

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt the coordinates you give to your `background` property, which should be respectively the `x` and `y` coordinates of the sprite in your image.

Let's imagine each of your color rect are `20px` width, `50px` height and have a `10px` margin between each other (in your image), you will do something like that to get the second image :

```
#a {
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url( '../img/a.png' ) 30px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

We define `x` as `30px`, because we skip one image (20px) + its margin (10px) ; `y` coordinates is still the same, ie 0
You also have to define correctly `width` and `height` properties, because they would be used to determine the background's size ; in my example, it tells the browser to get the part of image `a.png` from (30,0) to (30 + 20, 0 + 50 )

Is it clear ? You can also read [W3Schools article on CSS Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Comment: thank you.but as i mention the `a` div width will be 900px and height will be 40px;